# How can I quickly populate a Twitter list with selections from my main follow list?

Tags: twitter, list

I'm trying to populate a new Twitter list based on people who I follow and actually know in real life, which is a subset of the 700 that I follow overall.

Having created the list, I'm finding it really tedious (and the interface is slow) to pick through my following list to add people to it.  Is there a better way to:

- Add people to a list more quickly?
- Get suggestions based on who is in the list already (assuming some social graph connection would provide good suggestions)?

Answer (score 4):

There a couple of alternatives that allow you to select people from a Grid using check boxes.

- http://twitlistmanager.com/
- http://tweetbe.at/list-manager/

This is also [Pitupasa](http://pitupasa.com/lists/) that is in Beta. They have a couple of features that are *coming soon* which may interest you:

- Find people with shared interests
- People you reply/RT most often