# Can I add users to a Twitter list without going to their individual profile pages?

Tags: twitter, list

I have a Twitter list to which I would like to add about fifty user accounts. I have a handy (non-twitter) list of these user accounts, and I would like to be able to add them to the Twitter list without going to twitter.com/username and using the dropdown menu.

Is there an app or extension that will help me out with this? In the ideal picture in my mind, I can just type the username and hit enter, and that account will magically appear on my list.

Possible?

I have tried the solutions mentioned in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12873/how-can-i-quickly-populate-a-twitter-list-with-selections-from-my-main-follow-lis), but I do not follow the accounts I want to add to this list, so I haven't had any success.

Clarification:
I would like to be able to add users to a twitter list without loading a separate page to find each user. So I would like to avoid going to their user page, but I'd also like to avoid having to load a page of search results (whether on twitter.com or on an external app) each time, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to add users to a twitter list without loading a separate page to find each user. So I would like to avoid going to their user page, but I'd also like to **avoid having to load a page of search results (whether on twitter.com or on an external app) each time, as well**.

Using [Hootsuite](http://hootsuite.com) you [can do so](http://help.hootsuite.com/entries/243009-how-to-add-someone-to-a-twitter-list-through-column-preferences)

[image: hootsuite add to list]

Comment: Aha! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Comment: cheers @AbbyT.MillerΨ ( and hey, cool PSI! ;p )

Comment: thanks! I hang out on webapps.se on my own time, but I still get to sport the psi for... street cred purposes, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

http://tweetbe.at lets you search for any user, regardless of whether you are following them or not, and add them to a list.

Once you have authorised the app you enter your username in the search box at the top left.

- `user:@ATwitterUserName`
- click the button called `Add or remove from List`
- select the list you want to add the user to

They also provide a host of other features that you might find useful.

**EDIT**

You can also avoid visiting their profile page by using the Twitter search function. You simply

- search for the persons username
- click the drop down button next to the "Follow" button
- click `Add to list`
- select the list you want to add them to

Comment: These are good tips, and tweetbe.at will definitely work in a pinch. I'll update my question, though - it isn't so much that I don't to go to the person's twitter profile, and more that I want to add an account to the list without having to load any individual page (like a search page) at all.